# Removing spaces between single letters

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string that may contain an arbitrary number of single-letters separated by spaces. I am looking for a regex (in Perl) that will remove spaces between all (unknown number) of single letters.

For example:

`ab c d` should become `ab cd`

`a bcd e f gh` should become `a bcd ef gh`

`a b c` should become `abc`

and

`abc d` should be unchanged (because there are no single letters followed by or preceded by a single space).

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your description doesn't really match your examples.  It looks to me like you want to remove any space that is (1) preceded by a letter which is not itself preceded by a letter, and (2) followed by a letter which is not itself followed by a letter.  Those conditions can be expressed precisely as nested lookarounds:

```
/(?<=(?<!\pL)\pL) (?=\pL(?!\pL))/
```

tested:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::Simple tests => 4;

sub clean {
  (my $x = shift) =~ s/(?<=(?<!\pL)\pL) (?=\pL(?!\pL))//g;
  $x;
}

ok(clean('ab c d')        eq 'ab cd');
ok(clean('a bcd e f gh')  eq 'a bcd ef gh');
ok(clean('a b c')         eq 'abc');
ok(clean('ab c d')        eq 'ab cd');
```

output:

```
1..4
ok 1
ok 2
ok 3
ok 4
```

I'm assuming you really meant one space character (U+0020);  if you want to match any whitespace, you might want to replace the space with `\s+`.

Comment: Thanks. Your description is clearer than mine; this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with lookahead and lookbehind assertions, as described in [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

is(tran('ab c d'), 'ab cd');
is(tran('a bcd e f gh'), 'a bcd ef gh');
is(tran('a b c'), 'abc');
is(tran('abc d'), 'abc d');

sub tran
{
    my $input = shift;

    (my $output = $input) =~ s/(?<![[:lower:]])([[:lower:]]) (?=[[:lower:]])/$1/g;
    return $output;
}

done_testing;
```

Note the current code fails on the second test case, as the output is:

```
ok 1
not ok 2
#   Failed test at test.pl line 7.
#          got: 'abcd efgh'
#     expected: 'a bcd ef gh'
ok 3
ok 4
1..4
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 4.
```

I left it like this as your second and third examples seem to contradict each other as to how leading single characters should be handled. However, this framework should be enough to allow you to experiment with different lookaheads and lookbehinds to get the exact results you are looking for.

Comment: @Ether, I *really* like the testing demo.  But couldn't you pretty please fix it so it isn’t limited to working on 1960s ASCII? Unless an RFC says otherwise, I *always* want to see `[a-z]` written as something with the letter or alphabetic or lowercase property, depending what you’re doing. Probably just `\pL` is enough there. Also, I’m not clear on whether what he actually needs there is a single space, one or more spaces, or one or more whitespace characters.

Comment: @tchrist: as much as I hate complication, I think you're right here; unless one is writing something *extremely* quick and dirty (and possibly not even then..) one should always try to use the proper locale-adjustable character classes.

Comment: @Ether, have you had better luck with locales than I have? I find them so often broken that I I have much better luck with the Unicode properties than I do with the POSIX character classes. I am genuinely interested in your experiences because I have the pod for *Programming Perl* ’s regex chapter open in a vi window where I’m updating the part about POSIX character classes.

Comment: @tchrist: I haven't done much real text processing for several years now, but back in my spam-filtering days I don't recall running into any serious issues. I'm afraid I have nothing very helpful to contribute here.

Comment: @Ether: If you look on a Mac at the locales directory, you’ll see that Apple has symlinked a whole bunch of locales to US-ASCII! No kidding!  It’s perfectly abominable. Seeing that disgusting horror is why I swore off locales. Plus my other systems are all OpenBSD, which doesn’t really even have them. But the Unicode properties work always, so it’s a win.  Plus the hard comparison stuff looks like it may be taken care of for us via `Unicode::Collate::Locale`.

Comment: If I run your code I get this message: "POSIX syntax [: :] belongs inside character classes in regex;"

Comment: @sid_com: Yes, what POSIX calls a "character class" (e.g. `[:lower:]`) is not meant to be used alone, but inside another set of square brackets, like so: `[[:lower:]]`.  (POSIX calls the *outer* brackets and their contents a "bracket expression", but everyone else calls that a character class.)

Comment: @Ether, You have to admit that `/\p{Ll}/` wins big in conciseness over `/[[:lower:]]`. BTW, there are 1,759 code points that count as lowercase as of Unicode 6.0.  Instead of `\p{Ll}`, you can use `\p{Lowercase}` or `\p{Lowercase_Letter}`, and if you want to restrict its range, you could use `\p{Posix_Lower}` or `(?:(?=\p{ASCII})\p{Ll})` or `(?:(?=[\p{Latin}\p{Greek}])\p{Lowercase_Letter})`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @strings = ('a b c', 'ab c d', 'a bcd e f gh', 'abc d');

foreach my $string (@strings) {
   print "$string --> ";
   $string =~ s/\b(\w)\s+(?=\w\b)/$1/g; # the only line that actually matters
   print "$string\n";
}
```

prints this:

```
a b c --> abc
ab c d --> ab cd
a bcd e f gh --> a bcd ef gh
abc d --> abc d
```

I think/hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
my $str = ...;

$str =~ s/ \b(\w) \s+ (\w)\b /$1$2/gx;
```

That removes the space between all single nonspace characters.  Feel free to replace `\S` with a more restrictive character class if needed.  There also may be some edge cases related to punctuation characters that you need to deal with, but I can't guess that from the info you have provided.

As Ether helpfully points out, this fails on one case.  Here is a version that should work (though not quite as clean as the first):

```
s/ \b(\w) ( (?:\s+ \w\b)+ ) /$1 . join '', split m|\s+|, $2/gex;
```

I liked Ether's test based approach (imitation is the sincerest form of flattery and all):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Test::Magic tests => 4;

sub clean {
    (my $x = shift) =~ s{\b(\w) ((?: \s+ (\w)\b)+)}
                        {$1 . join '', split m|\s+|, $2}gex;
    $x
}

test 'space removal',
  is clean('ab c d')       eq 'ab cd',
  is clean('a bcd e f gh') eq 'a bcd ef gh',
  is clean('a b c')        eq 'abc',
  is clean('abc d')        eq 'abc d';
```

returns:

```
1..4
ok 1 - space removal 1
ok 2 - space removal 2
ok 3 - space removal 3
ok 4 - space removal 4
```

Comment: That fails on the third case: it produces `'ab c'`.

Comment: I’m pretty certain that you’ve have made the distressingly common error of thinking that a `\b`  it does something that it does not do. Strings like `"="` or `"\t=\t"` will be matched by **neither** `/\S\b/` nor `/\b\S/`, whereas strings like `"a"` or `"\ta\t"` **will** be matched by both of those patterns. People often use  `\b` incorrectly because of this, and become surprised by the results.

Comment: @tchrist => good point, i was just trying to make the accepted problem space larger, changing `\S` to `\w` should shrink the space back down and clean up the subtle errors.  I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to add in support for `\W` characters

Answer (score 0):

It's not a regex but since I am lazy by nature I would it do this way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;

my @strings = ('a b c', 'ab c d', 'a bcd e f gh', 'abc d');
for my $string ( @strings ) {
    my @s; my $t = '';
    for my $el ( split /\s+/, $string ) {
        if ( length $el > 1 ) {
        push @s, $t if $t;
        $t = '';
        push @s, $el;
        } else { $t .= $el; }
    }
    push @s, $t if $t;
    say "@s";
}
```

OK, my way is the slowest:

```
no_regex   130619/s         --       -60%       -61%       -63%
Alan_Moore 323328/s       148%         --        -4%        -8%
Eric_Storm 336748/s       158%         4%         --        -5%
canavanin  352654/s       170%         9%         5%         --
```

I didn't include Ether's code because ( as he has tested ) it returns different results.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have the slowest and the fastest.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.012;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);
my @strings = ('a b c', 'ab c d', 'a bcd e f gh', 'abc d');

cmpthese( 0, {
    Eric_Storm  => sub{ for my $string (@strings) { $string =~ s{\b(\w) ((?: \s+ (\w)\b)+)}{$1 . join '', split m|\s+|, $2}gex; } },
    canavanin   => sub{ for my $string (@strings) { $string =~ s/\b(\w)\s+(?=\w\b)/$1/g; } },
    Alan_Moore  => sub{ for my $string (@strings) { $string =~ s/(?<=(?<!\pL)\pL) (?=\pL(?!\pL))//g; } },
    keep_uni    => sub{ for my $string (@strings) { $string =~ s/\PL\pL\K (?=\pL(?!\pL))//g; } },
    keep_asc    => sub{ for my $string (@strings) { $string =~ s/[^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\K (?=[a-zA-Z](?![a-zA-Z]))//g; } },
    no_regex    => sub{ for my $string (@strings) { my @s; my $t = ''; 
    for my $el (split /\s+/, $string) {if (length $el > 1) { push @s, $t if $t; $t = ''; push @s, $el; } else { $t .= $el; } }
    push @s, $t if $t;
    #say "@s";
    } },
});
```

.

```
           Rate  no_regex Alan_Moore Eric_Storm canavanin  keep_uni keep_asc                                                                                                                                                             
no_regex    98682/s        --       -64%       -65%      -66%      -81%     -87%                                                                                                                                                             
Alan_Moore 274019/s      178%         --        -3%       -6%      -48%     -63%                                                                                                                                                             
Eric_Storm 282855/s      187%         3%         --       -3%      -46%     -62%                                                                                                                                                             
canavanin  291585/s      195%         6%         3%        --      -45%     -60%
keep_uni   528014/s      435%        93%        87%       81%        --     -28%
keep_asc   735254/s      645%       168%       160%      152%       39%       --
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job.

```
(?<=\b\w)\s(?=\w\b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have written simple javascript to do this it's simple and you can convert into any language.

```js
function compressSingleSpace(source){

    let words = source.split(" ");
  let finalWords = [];
  let tempWord = "";

  for(let i=0;i<words.length;i++){

   if(tempWord!='' && words[i].length>1){
    finalWords.push(tempWord);
    tempWord = '';
   }

   if(words[i].length>1){
    finalWords.push(words[i]);
   }else{
    tempWord += words[i];
   }

  }

  if(tempWord!=''){
   finalWords.push(tempWord);
  }

  source = finalWords.join(" ");
    
    return source;

}


function convertInput(){
  let str = document.getElementById("inputWords").value;
  document.getElementById("firstInput").innerHTML = str;
  
  let compressed = compressSingleSpace(str);
    document.getElementById("finalOutput").innerHTML = compressed;
}
```

```css
label{
    font-size:20px;
    margin:10px;
}
input{
    margin:10px;
    font-size:15px;
    padding:10px;
}

input[type="button"]{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: #ccc;
}

#firstInput{
  color:red;
  font-size:20px;
  margin:10px;
}

#finalOutput{
  color:green;
  font-size:20px;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<label for="inputWords">Enter your input and press Convert</label><br>
<input id="inputWords" value="check this site p e t z l o v e r . c o m thanks">
<input type="button" onclick="convertInput(this.value)" value="Convert" >
<div id="firstInput">check this site p e t z l o v e r . c o m thanks</div>
<div id="finalOutput">check this site petzlover.com thanks</div>
```