# How to remove spaces in an acronym in SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to write a function that removes spaces between isolated letters, like in an acronym.

For example, if I have:

```
'I B M Computers' i need to have in return 'IBM Computers'
' I B M ' => 'IBM'
'Computers A B' => 'Computers AB'
'Computers A BC' => 'Computers A BC' (nothing changes)
'Computers A B CD' => 'Computers AB CD'
'Computers A B C D' => 'Computers ABCD'
```

I can't find a way to do that properly, can someone help me please ?

Thanks.

Comment: so you have full list of acronym letters

Comment: no, i don't have a list of acronyms.

Comment: so how you will you match this acronyms words or not in data

Comment: In fact i don't really care if the acronym exists or not, if i have two isolated letters, i need to remove the space between them.

Comment: No you have to make some list because machine does nor read your mind which carry isolated letters

Comment: I think there is a way to code the fact that if a letter is separated by two spaces and another letter is the same way, you remove the space between them... I've done that in others languages but i'm struggling with sql.

Comment: so you have two space in filed values right?

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand your question. Have you seen the examples i wrote ? I have edited with some more.

Comment: the pattern you want to replace is space character space replacing it with character space should in theory remove the first two spaces as they follow the pattern and ignore the last space as it's pattern is space character character. However I am not clever enough to work out a regular expression/built in string function solution to utilize it

Comment: ignore that it doesn't work for Computers A B

Comment: you can't really go over it iteratively, (running over multiple times until there are no single letters) Because `Computers A B C` will turn to `Computers AB C` after the first pass, and then the code would ignore it. You somehow need to evaluate the entire string at once.

Comment: Is there any possibility that there would be multiple acronyms in the string?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could have 'computers a b computers c d' => 'computers ab computers cd' but i will never have 'computers a b c d' => 'computers ab cd', i'll have 'computers abcd' instead. So only one acronym between two words.
I hope it's clear, i'm sorry english is not my first language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex as described in this post should work for you (with a little tweaking of the regex for MariaDB).  From that post by @Alan Moore:
"It looks to me like you want to remove any space that is (1) preceded by a letter which is not itself preceded by a letter, and (2) followed by a letter which is not itself followed by a letter. Those conditions can be expressed precisely as nested lookarounds".  Please give credit to him.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233386/2543416

So assuming your column is called 'DESC', your answer will be:

```
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(DESC, '(?<=(?<![[:alpha:]])[[:alpha:]]) +(?=[[:alpha:]](?![[:alpha:]]))','')) AS fixed_desc
FROM table;
```

[Test the regex here](https://regex101.com/r/5QFUqW/2)

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis:`(?<=(?<!\pL)\pL) (?=\pL(?!\pL))` should work.

Comment: @chrisw Thanks, fixed

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The regex works perfectly, but the regexp_replace() doesn't seem to work... Nothing is replaced in my string.

Comment: for instance, SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('a b', '(?<=(?<!\pL)\pL) (?=\pL(?!\pL))','') AS fixed_desc; returns 'a b'

Comment: if i replace \pL by \. it works for 'a b' but that's it. It doesn't work if there are other letters in the string...

Comment: I forgot to put the the captured groups to replace with in the third argument. It captures the groups on either side of the space and returns them, less the space.  I suspect this may not work when there are consecutive letters though now that I think about it.  It may take some tweaking of the look-ahead and look-behind regex's.

Comment: Wait, I don't want captured groups.  I want the space that is surrounded by the single letters as described by the regex and replace it with nothing.  If it didn't work, then the criteria was not matched.  Try the other examples.  I'm afraid I do not have MariaDB to test with. regex101 seems to find that space?

Comment: Thank you. I believe it's not the same syntax with mariadb, i've found that `SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(DESC, '[[:<:]](.) (.)[[:>:]]','\\1\\2')) AS fixed_desc` works for two separate letters. I can't find a way to make it work for multiple separate letters. But there's progress, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @BixOuille I got it!  I changed the unicode notation to POSIX shorthand and it worked. I installed MariaDB to make sure :-) Maybe it's a MariaDB implementation issue.  Not uncommon with regex engines, not all applications of it are created equal :-/ anyway, see my edit above.

Comment: Waouh perfect ! It works like a charm, thank you so much ! (remove your link to the regex test maybe ?)

Comment: Make sure you mark this as the answer if it solved it for you!

Comment: @BixOuille Thanks I updated the regex101 example for future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ltrim and rtrim functions.
Example:
Update 'table' Set campo=ltrim(rtrim(campo))

Comment: thanks for your answer but it will only remove the spaces on the left and on the right, not taking care of spaces in the string. And, as suggested by another person, the replace function will remove all the spaces, whitch is not what i expect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the replace function to strip spaces out of both sides of the comparison.

But do note that this will be inefficient, as your query will not be able to use indexes

```
REPLACE(mystring,' ','')
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql

Comment: thank you for your answer, the replace function will remove all the spaces, which is not what i expect. 'Computers A B' will become 'ComputersAB' and i expect 'Computers AB'