# Delphi - Removing spaces between single letters

Tags: regex, delphi

I have the same task as in this question: [Question about spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228750/), but as a newbie I need to convert the best answer to Delphi language (10.3 Rio) using `TRegExp`.

The other task is resolved this way:

```
with RegExp do
begin
  Subject := Tmp;                                  // присваиваем Ф.И.О. уже ранее очищенным от суффиксов
  RegEx := '^(.*) van de (.*)$';                     // проверяем на наличие "van de" в Ф.И.О.
  if Match then
  begin
    Replacement := '\1 \2';
    temp2 := RegExp.ComputeReplacement;
    lstListAllFiles.Items.AddObject('index='+IntToStr(i)+' Найден префикс van de: "'+Tmp+'"', TObject(clOlive));
    Tmp := temp2;
    RecordFileName[i].OnlyPrefixAuthor := 'van de ';
    lstListAllFiles.Items.AddObject('          Будет заменен на: "'+Tmp+'"', TObject(clOlive));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What's the trouble with writing as a string? `RegEx:='(?<=(?<!\p{L})\p{L}) (?=\p{L}(?!\p{L}))'`

Answer (score 0):

So, I solve my task (with some trick):

```
Str:=RegExpIO.Replace(Str,'(?<=(?<!\p{L})\p{L})\s(?=\p{L}(?!\p{L}))','')
Str:=ReplaceText(Str,'_','');
```

1st line search single character and deletes whitespace between them. This work for that type sentences: "**Wendy V Poll**", "**Wendy V К Poll**".

2nd line is trick for that type sentences: "**Wendy V V R Poll**", "**Wendy V К R R Poll**" and so on.